# Is there a way to do namespaces like in C for bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, programming

What I'm talking about is like in C, you get to use namespaces with the statement `using namespace blah blah blah`, can you do the same thing but in bash?

Comment: Nope not in C, but C++. Pretty different languages, share a pretty similar syntax, but namespaces are not a feature of C

Comment: Many times when people ask about bash or some other shell they really mean Unix tools so - if you were going to be manipulating text in a shell then you'd probably call awk to do so and then GNU awk does have namespaces. If you think you need namespaces for shell then you're probably using the wrong tool.

Comment: _Side note:_ I used to write shell scripts [decades ago]. I stopped doing that when I discovered `perl`. So, every script that I used to write in a shell (e.g. `bash`, `tcsh`, etc.) is now a perl script. And, perl has namespaces [packages]. And, [if you must] `python` has namespaces. So, IMO, rather than try to contort bash into doing something it doesn't really want to do, I'd rather switch than fight :-)

Answer (score 10):

Well, there is no namespaces in C, in C++ - yes, there are. But none in C.

And no, there are no namespaces in `bash` either. `bash` has three name spaces - for local variables, functions and environment variables. So you can have variable `foo` and function `foo()` at the same time. But not two different `foo()` functions. If define them - the second will always override the first.

In `bash`, if you really need to deal with name conflicts - the common solution is to give prefixes or suffixes to the sourced variables and/or functions.

Comment: As a history note: in the Bourne shell, variables and functions shared the same namespace; you couldn't have a function and a variable by the same name at the same time.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas,  I was taking about `GNU bash`.

Comment: Sure, that's understood. That was just a *history  note*, bash being the Bourne-Again SHell (though it's more Korn-like than Bourne-like).

Comment: Shell variables and environment variables also share a namespace. Environment variables are created by exporting shell variables.

Comment: Well _technically_ (with extra emphasis) C has namespaces, just that they are fixed. One space for labels, one for identifiers, etc :)

Answer (score 0):

No, bash doesn't have namespaces, per-se. However, you could build up a library of bash modules that you then can selectively import into any given script, by using the `source` command. In fact, you can write an `import` function to emulate the syntax of modern programming languages.

For example, you could do something like the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
[[ -e "$HOME/libbash/core.sh" ]] && {
    source "$HOME/libbash/core.sh"
}
include "string"   # sources $HOME/libbash/string.sh
include "fs/msys"  # sources $HOME/libbash/fs/msys.sh"
```

This expects the ~/libbash folder to contain core.sh with the following definition for import:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#echo "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
LIBBASHDIR="$HOME/libbash"

import () {
    for f in "$@"; do
        if [[ -f "$LIBBASHDIR/$f.sh" ]]; then
            source "$LIBBASHDIR/$f.sh"
        else
            echo >&2 "import: not found: '$f.sh'"
        fi
    done
}
```

That script will only work on your system, which defeats one of the most common use-cases for bash scripting: creating install scripts that work on other people's systems. But, it sure can save you a bunch of time if you find yourself repeating the same idioms a bunch while scripting on one or more machines you control.